# Windows Server 2016 - Can't Access through RDP - The Local Security Authority cannot be contacted

Tags: windows-server-2016, rdp

I recently setup Windows Server 2016 as a VM on VMWare but I can't RDP into the server. I get the following error:

> An authentication error has occurred. The Local Security Authority
>   cannot be contacted. Remote computer [myserver] This could be due to
>   an expired password...

This computer is going to be a stand-alone web server and is not a Domain Controller.I have enabled remote connections by:

- In the Remote section of System Properties, Enabled Allow Remote Conntection to the computer and unchecked "Allow connections only form computers running Remote Desktop with Network Level" Authentication (recommended)"

What am I missing?

Comment: I've seen this caused by Symantec blocking the LSA from communicating with the domain controller. Happened within a day of server build due to Windows Updates being installed.

If you access the server via VMware console, then access local users and groups > groups to check the members of Administrators, does it resolve the domain accounts or list a bunch of SIDs instead?

Also, it could be the Computer Machine Password needs reset.

Comment: No Symantec stuff installed on the server. There is no domain. Both logins work fine through the console so it is not a password issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After endless searching, it turns out the problem was I had the IP address for the server assigned to another server and when I thought I was RDPing to my new server, I was actually  RDPing into an older server. So nothing I attempted to do on the new server made the least bit of difference as I was never actually hitting the new server.

Perhaps my stupidity will help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

open `cmd` and Type
`ping <server-name or server-ip>`
if above condition is *OK* (if you block the ping on firewall its OK)

`nbtstat -a <server-ip-address>`

you will get the domain-name on one first line under the section of NAME
After that

login with `<domain-name>\administrator`

Password   `********`

let me know if this method will not resolve your issue

Comment: I get this in response:
Ethernet1:
Node IpAddress: [myip] Scope Id: []
    Host not found.

Comment: @EfficionDave are you using static or dynamic IP?

Comment: The server is a static IP.

Comment: @EfficionDave are you able to ping the device?

Comment: No, but I don't see how that is relevant. I am definitely connecting to the device when I try to RDC, it is the login that is failing but that same login works fine through the VM Console.

Comment: @EfficionDave if you are  unable to ping the device, so i will advice you to login back into console again and verify your IP address, subnet-mask, gateway and very important DNS. After that if you still unable to connect then disable/enable your network adaptor. Otherwise without pinging the device unless your firewall block it, you will not able to RDP.

Comment: As I said in the comment above, RDP is reaching the server fine if it wasn't, I wouldn't be getting the login screen at all. Ping is disabled by default for Windows Server 2016 and I'm not modifying the Firewall to allow it through because that wouldn't do anything to solve my problem.

Comment: @EfficionDave
For nbtstat -a return host not found,it could be these reasons:

1.The NetBIOS Interface device on the target computer is not started.

REF:https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/175935


2. The nbtstat -a command with a remote computer and the name of the computer is resolved by Domain Name System (DNS)REF:https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/249874


3.And you also could try to change to 'Enable NetBIOS over tcp/ip' in NIC properties>ipv4>advance>wins.

Comment: @EfficionDave also check the DNS entry.

Answer (score 0):

I would try making sure that the time / time zones on both devices are synced. I know it sounds silly, but I have read that this causes issues in the past

Also, have you added yourself to the local "Remote Desktop Users" group?

Comment: Time / Time zones are matched properly. Both users I've tried are both Administrators and were already in the Remote Desktop Users group. Thanks though.